# Downloading data from multiple-pages website with requests method in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, parameters, get, python-requests

I have this API documentation of the website http://json-homework.task-sss.krasilnikov.spb.ru/docs/9f66a575a6cfaaf7e43177317461d057 (which is only in Russian, unfortunately, but I'll try to explain), and I am to import the data about the group members from there, but the issue is that parameter `page` returns only 5 members, and when you increase the page number, it only returns next 5 members, not adding them to the previous five. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests as rq
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
url='http://json-homework.task-sss.krasilnikov.spb.ru/api/groups/getmembers?api_key=9f66a575a6cfaaf7e43177317461d057&group_id=4508123&page=1'
data=rq.get(url)
data1=json.loads(data.text)
data1=json_normalize(json.loads(data.text)["response"])
data1
```

and here is what my output looks like: [image: my output]

By entering bigger and bigger numbers, I also found out that the last part of data exists on 41 page, i.e. I need to get the data from 1 to 41 page. How can I include all the pages in my code? Maybe it is possible with some loop or something like that, I don't know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the API documentation, there is no parameter to specify the users to fetch in one page, so you will have to get them 5 at a time, and since there are 41 pages you can just loop through the urls.

```py
import requests as rq
import json

all_users = []
for page in range(1,42):
    url=f'http://json-homework.task-sss.krasilnikov.spb.ru/api/groups/getmembers?api_key=9f66a575a6cfaaf7e43177317461d057&group_id=4508123&page={page}'
    data=rq.get(url)
    all_users.append(json.loads(data.text)["response"])
```

The above implementation, will of course not check for any api throttling i.e. the API may give unexpected data if too many requests are made in a very short duration, which you can mitigate using some well placed delays.

Comment: I get this error now "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"...

Comment: replace the last line in my code with this `all_users = all_users + json.loads(data.text)["response"]`, then you can run `all_users` through `json_normalize`

Comment: oh, it still gives me this error on this line `all_users = all_users + json.loads(data.text)`

Comment: I ran the above code and it works fine on my end. Can you print `data.text` within the loop and check if you are getting valid json as a string? also what python version are you using?

Comment: here is my output of `json_normalize(all_users)`

```
            id first_name   last_name
0    212442289      Darya     Glazova
1    303958499     Alexey         Kim
2     51058438      Masha      Isaeva
3     97510651      Pavel   Kuznitsyn
4    175877310      Irina  Prokopyeva
..         ...        ...         ...
198  263149712     Fyodor      Osipov
199  169412107      Maria       Frank
200   68937678      Denis   Yurchenko
201  172735591      Sasha   Zavyalova
202  375195548      Sofia    Tarasova

[203 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: I'm using 3.7.4 version on Jupyter Notebook. If you meant to just check what `data.text` would give in the loop, it only gives me DOCTYPE html and so on...

Comment: thats not what it should be data.text should be a parsable json. visit the url from your api endpont in your browser itself and make sure you get json [http://json-homework.task-sss.krasilnikov.spb.ru/api/groups/getmembers?api_key=9f66a575a6cfaaf7e43177317461d057&group_id=4508123&page=1](http://json-homework.task-sss.krasilnikov.spb.ru/api/groups/getmembers?api_key=9f66a575a6cfaaf7e43177317461d057&group_id=4508123&page=1). anything else will not be correctly parsed. If you are getting DOCTYPE html, it may indicate some access restriction to the api endpoint